# Delivery days in cities using array () PHP

Tags: php, arrays, date

I have an arrangement with the delivery days of my online store in two different cities:

```
$city1 = array("Monday", "Friday");

$city2 = array("Monday", "Thursday", "Saturday");
```

The store delivers every 2 days, but only on certain days depending on the city.

If today is Thursday and someone buys in city 1, the order will be received in 2 days in this case on Monday (see above array).

If today is Thursday and someone buys in the city 2, the order will be received in 2 days, here on Saturday.

Based on the above, how I can do with PHP to know what day you receive the product?

What should be the logic of programming?

Comment: I would convert the days into numbers from 0-7 and then take your input e.g. `Thursday` -> 4 and then increment that number (0-7) until you found it in your array, means `Monday` in city 1.

Answer (score 0):

For getting the receive day you could do something like this

```
<?php

$days = array("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday");

$city1 = array("Monday","Thursday");

$city2 = array("Monday", "Thursday", "Saturday");

$cities = array("city1" => $city1,"city2" => $city2);

//returns the receive day actually the index for $days array
function get_day($city,$order_date){
    global $days;
    $key = array_keys($days,$order_date);
    $key = $key[0];
    $receive_day = getnexttwo($key+2,$city);
    return $receive_day;
}
//Utility to iterate by 2
function getnexttwo($key,$city){
    global $cities,$days;
    $next_day_key = $key%7;

    if(in_array($days[$next_day_key],$cities[$city])){
        return $next_day_key;
    }
    return getnexttwo($next_day_key+2,$city);
}

$order_day =  $days[get_day("city2","Saturday")]; 
echo $order_day;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so easy to explain but

I've replaced the day names with numbers so I can calculate the next one.

0 is Sunday, 1 Monday and so on.

```
function run()
{
    $delivery = 2; // 2 days

    $city1 = array(1, 5); // Monday, Friday
    $city2 = array(1, 4, 6); // Monday, Thursday, Saturday

    // 0 = Sunday

    $today = 4; // Thursday

    $delivery1 = get_delivery_day($city1, $today, $delivery);
    echo "Order in city1 gets delivered $delivery1\n";

    $delivery2 = get_delivery_day($city2, $today, $delivery);
    echo "Order in city2 gets delivered $delivery2\n";
}

function get_delivery_day($city, $today, $delivery)
{
    echo "Trying to deliver\n";
    echo "Today is $today\n";
    echo "city " . implode(',', $city) . "\n";
    // delivery must be zero or lower, and city must deliver today
    // looping before it happens
    while ($delivery > 0 || !in_array($today, $city))
    {
        $today++; // time is increasing by day
        $today %= 7; // if 7 then 0 - looping from Saturday to Sunday
        // remaining days are decreasing
        $delivery--; // can be lower than 0 because it would break >0 condition
        echo "today $today, remaining days $delivery, city " . implode('-', $city) ."\n";
    }

    return $today; // today it will get delivered
}

run();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, the store needs at least two days to delivery, right?

If so, you can try something like this:

```
function guess_delivery_day($order_city, $order_day) {
    $delivery_days = array(

        //index of the week days are based on date('N'), see http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
        'city1' => array(1 => "Monday", 5 => "Friday"),

        'city2' => array(1 => "Monday", 4 =>"Thursday", 6 => "Saturday")
    );

    if (isset($delivery_days[$order_city])) {
        $guessed_day = $order_day + 2; //Assuming the store take at least two days to ship a product;

        if ($guessed_day > 7) {
            $guessed_day = $guessed_day - 7; //If bigger then 7, it will be shipped on the next week
        }

        if (isset($delivery_days[$order_city][$guessed_day])) {
            return $delivery_days[$order_city][$guessed_day]; //we got lucky and the guessed day matches a delivery day
        }

        end($delivery_days[$order_city]); //set the pointer at the end of the array
        if ($guessed_day > key($delivery_days[$order_city])) {
            reset($delivery_days[$order_city]); //set the pointer at begining of the array
            return current($delivery_days[$order_city]); //the delivery day will be the first day available on that city
        }

        //We search for the following delivery days
        for($i = $guessed_day; $i <= 7; $i++) {
            if (isset($delivery_days[$order_city][$i])) {
                return $delivery_days[$order_city][$i];
            }
        }

        return false; //Something is wrong, it shouldn't be reached

    } else {
        return false; //Something is wrong with this order;
    }
}
```