# Complex time interval check in PHP

Tags: php, date, php-carbon

I have a complex time interval check I'm struggling to solve. Here is the problem:

I need to dynamically calculate pick up time for orders.
Orders from Monday 10:01am till Wednesday 10am will be delivered on Friday. Orders from Wednesday 10:01 till Friday 10:00am will be delivered on  the following Monday. 
Orders from Friday 10:01am till Monday 10:00am will be delivered on 
following Wednesday.

I'm working in PHP and using Carbon (http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) and the order placement time will be Carbon::now()

Comment: you want to calculate time diff between two dates

Comment: What's the actual question? What have you tried? I can't tell what part you're getting stuck at.

Comment: There's very similar question to yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37196603/delivery-days-in-cities-using-array-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for my previous code. I checked and found several flaws there. I have rewritten the code and here is complete and working solution for you. You can have a look over the conditions to figure out what I've done:

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Karachi'); // set default timezone if needed
    $time = new DateTime();
    $day = $time->format('l');
    $IntervalA = new DateTime('10:01');
    $IntervalB = new DateTime('10:00');

    // for friday delivery
    if(in_array($day, array('Monday', 'Tuesday')) AND $time >= $IntervalA OR in_array($day, array('Wednesday')) AND $time <= $IntervalB) {
        echo "The product will be delivered on Friday";
    }

    // for monday delivery
    if(in_array($day, array('Wednesday', 'Thursday')) AND $time >= $IntervalA OR in_array($day, array('Friday')) AND $time <= $IntervalB) {
        echo "The product will be delivered on Monday";
    }

    // for wednesday delivery
    if(in_array($day, array('Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday')) AND $time >= $IntervalA OR in_array($day, array('Monday')) AND $time <= $IntervalB) {
        echo "The product will be delivered on Wednesday";
    }
```

Comment: Thank you rehmat! Solution works perfectly

Comment: @RiaanZA Glad to know that it worked :)